# My php script can't be executed well (XmlHttpReqest)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've a toggle button on my website. This btn toggles Start / Stop. When the page loads, the value of the button is Start. When i click for the first time on the button the button will swap from start to stop. On a second click it goes on the other way but it is at this moment that my php script needs to be executed. This works fine.

When my PHP code runs, it stops at the first if statement and the output is `Did not hit the button`, but i did it twice. Do you know why the rest of my code do not want to be executed?

***HTML CODE***

```
<div id="row3">
            <form action="./includes/insert_data.php" method="POST">
                <div id="zone_area">
                    <p><input type="text" name="zone_field" id="zone_field" placeholder="Enter a zone" autocomplete="off"></p>
                </div>
                <div id="button_area">
                <p><input onclick="clickHandler();" type="button" value="Start" id="toggle_btn" name="toggle_btn"></p>
                </div>
            </form>
</div>
```

***Javascript CODE***

```
var numberOfClicks = 0; 

    function clickHandler(){
        numberOfClicks++;
        if (numberOfClicks % 2 == 1) {
            firstClick();
        } else { 
            secondClick();
        } 
    }
    
    function firstClick(){
        var toggle_btn = document.getElementById("toggle_btn");
        var zone_field = document.getElementById("zone_field");

        var zone_table = document.getElementById("zone_table");
        var avg_div = document.getElementById("row5");

        //zone_field.disabled = true;
        toggle_btn.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        toggle_btn.style.border = "1px solid black";
        toggle_btn.value = "Stop";
        toggle_btn.style.transition = "all 0.2s ease";

        $(avg_div).slideDown(300);
        zone_table.innerHTML = zone_field.value;
    }
    function secondClick(){
        var toggle_btn = document.getElementById("toggle_btn");
        var zone_field = document.getElementById("zone_field");

        var avg_div = document.getElementById("row5");

        //zone_field.disabled = false;
        toggle_btn.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        toggle_btn.value = "Start";
        toggle_btn.style.transition = "all 0.2s ease";

        $(avg_div).slideUp(300);

        zone_field.value = '';

        callPHP();
    }

    function callPHP(){                                // HERE I DO CALL MY PHP SCRIPT
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open("POST", "includes/insert_data.php", false);
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };

        http.send();
    }
```

***PHP CODE***

```
<?php

include_once("./conn.php");

if(isset($_POST["toggle_btn"])){
    if(!empty($_POST["zone_field"])){

        $sql = "SELECT SUM(waarde) AS total_sum, COUNT(waarde) AS total_count FROM results";
        $res = $conn->query($sql);

        $Name = $_POST["zone_field"];
        $Time = 10;

        if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {

                $avg = $row["total_sum"] / $row["total_count"];

                $sql = "INSERT INTO measurements (Name, Time, AVG_ms) VALUES(?, ?, ?);";
                
                if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
                    // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $Name, $Time, $avg);

                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                    
                    header("Location: ../results.php");
                
                } else{
                    echo "ERROR: Could not prepare query: $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
                }
            } 
          } else {
            echo "No rows have been found";
          }

          $conn->close();
    }
} else {
    echo 'Did not hit the btn';
}

?>
```

Comment: Use `preventDefault()` to stop bubbling in the click handler.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Is it possible to write write your idea bellow down, please?